# How to add to an array in another PHP file?

Tags: php

I am trying to add to another array located in php file in the most efficient way. Is this possible?

For example if the PHP file was

```
<?php 

$lang['Hello']          = 'Hello';
$lang['Welcome']        = 'Welcome';

?>
```

What code would I need to add to this array from another PHP file in order for it to become

```
<?php 

$lang['Hello']          = 'Hello';
$lang['Welcome']        = 'Welcome';
$lang['Test']           = 'Test';

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `return` feature from PHP files to return an array.

### First array

Let's call this file `first_array.php`.

```
<?php

return [
    'Hello' => 'Hello',
    'Welcome' => 'Welcome',
];
```

### Second array

Let's call this file `second_array.php`.

```
<?php

$arr = require __DIR__ . '/first_array.php';

$arr['Test'] = 'Test';

return $arr;
```

### Test

```
<?php

$arr = require __DIR__ . '/second_array.php';

var_dump($arr);
```

would give

```
array(3) {
  ["Hello"]=>
  string(5) "Hello"
  ["Welcome"]=>
  string(7) "Welcome"
  ["Test"]=>
  string(4) "Test"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_merge` and include functions.

```
<?php
$lang['tr'] = [
'hello'=>'Merhaba',
'howdy'=>'Naber?'
];
$lang['en'] = include 'lang.en.php';
```

in your `lang.en.php` file:

```
<?php
return [
'hello'=>'Hello',
'howdy'=>'How are you?',
];
```

Or you can try `array_merge` approach:

```
<?php
$lang['tr'] = [
'hello'=>'Merhaba',
'howdy'=>'Naber?'
];
$lang = array_merge($lang,(include 'lang.en.php'));
```

in your lang.en.php file:

```
<?php
return [
'en'=> [
'hello'=>'Hello',
'howdy'=>'How are you?',
],
];
```